# In the R package spANOVA can coordinates be entered directly as Lat/Longs or is a map projection required?

Tags: anova, spatial, gis

I have some data on fish abundance in a harbour in Canada that I'm analyzing using the R package [spANOVA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spANOVA/spANOVA.pdf) (Spatial ANOVA). I'm using the function aovSAR.gen which takes the arguments:

aovSar.gen(formula, coord, seq.radius, data = NULL)

Where coord is defined as: "A matrix or data.frame of point coordinates"

Can I plug Lat/Longs into this section or do I need to choose a projection for my points first to account for the curvature of the earth?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from the author of the package:

As this model works with distance computation you need to use a projected CRS (e.g UTM).
Distance is distorted using a geographic lat lon CRS.
You can transform your data projection using spTransform (sp package).